# Is .NET “double” arithmetic independent of platform/architecture?

Tags: c#, .net

If I run a complex calculation involving `System.Double` on .NET under Windows (x86 and x64) and then on Mono (Linux, Unix, whatever), am I *absolutely guaranteed* to get *exactly* the same result in all cases, or does the specification allow for some leeway in the calculation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> In addition, the loss of precision
>   that results from arithmetic,
>   assignment, and parsing operations
>   with Double values may differ by
>   platform. For example, the result of
>   assigning a literal Double value may
>   differ in the 32-bit and 64-bit
>   versions of the .NET Framework

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that results *are* always guaranteed to be IEEE-754-compliant, but that spec allows a certain amount of leeway (for example, results are allowed to be more precise than the specified minimum precision).

Answer (score 5):

No its not the same. It might compile to x87 or SSE instructions which work differently(for example regarding denorm support). I found no way to force .net to use reproducible floating point math.

There are some alternatives, but all of them are slow and some are a lot of work:

- Implement your own floating/fixed-point numbers.

  - 32-bit fixed aren't too difficult to code. But their limited range and precision make them hard to work with. `Log` and `Sqrt` will be slow. If you want I can dig out my unfinished code for this.
  - 64-bit fixed-point are better to work with. But you can't easily implement them in high performance way in byte-code, since some intermediate values are 96-128 bit for which the CLR doesn't offer support.
  - floating-point (I'd look into 32 bit mantissa and 16 bit exponent) are nice to work with, but hard to implement. Since to avoid precision loss you need a quick way to find the highest non zero bit. And there are no BitScanForward/Reverse intrinsics in C#/.net.
- Move all your math code into native libraries, since from what I read you can force most C++ compilers into creating reproducible floating-point code.
- `Decimal` is implemented in software and thus probably reproducible too, but it isn't fast either.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so. Such phrases as:

> The size of the internal floatingpoint
>   representation is implementation-dependent, can vary, and shall have precision at least as great as that of
>   the variable or expression being represented

and:

> This design allows the CLI to choose a platform-specific high-performance representation for
>   floating-point numbers until they are placed in storage locations. For example, it might be able to leave
>   floating-point variables in hardware registers that provide more precision than a user has requested. At the
>   same time, CIL generators can force operations to respect language-specific rules for representations through
>   the use of conversion instructions

from section 12.1.3 of MS Partition I would tend to indicate that rounding differences might occur if all operations occur within the internal representation