# Is .NET “decimal” arithmetic independent of platform/architecture?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I asked about `System.Double` recently and was told that computations may differ depending on platform/architecture. Unfortunately, I cannot find any information to tell me whether the same applies to `System.Decimal`.

Am I guaranteed to get *exactly* the same result for any particular `decimal` computation independently of platform/architecture?

Comment: Depends on how you're making your decimals I guess.

Comment: The problem with doubles applies in C++, but as Jeff Yates stated, it is standardized in .NET. Whether for example Mono really adheres to this standard is a different matter of course.

Comment: @mzabsky It was a recent question of his: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017530/is-net-double-arithmetic-independent-of-platform-architecture

Comment: @mzabsky: The C# spec actually states that hardware architectures may have some impact on floating point types. See section 4.1.6 of the C#3.0 spec.

Comment: @mzabsky I could be wrong, but I think his concern was 32 vs 64 bit platforms and differing cpu abilities?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Am I guaranteed to get exactly the same result for any particular decimal computation independently of platform/architecture?

The **C# 4 spec** is clear that the *value* you get will be computed the same on any platform.

As LukeH's answer notes, the ECMA version of the C# 2 spec grants leeway to conforming implementations to provide more precision, so an implementation of C# 2.0 on another platform might provide a higher-precision answer.

For the purposes of this answer I'll just discuss the C# 4.0 specified behaviour.

The C# 4.0 spec says:

---

> The result of an operation on values of type decimal is that which would result from calculating an exact result (preserving scale, as defined for each operator) and then rounding to fit the representation. Results are rounded to the nearest representable value, and, when a result is equally close to two representable values, to the value that has an even number in the least significant digit position [...]. A zero result always has a sign of 0 and a scale of 0.

---

Since the calculation of the exact value of an operation should be the same on any platform, and the rounding algorithm is well-defined, the resulting value should be the same regardless of platform.

However, note the parenthetical and that last sentence about the zeroes. It might not be clear why that information is necessary.

One of the oddities of the decimal system is that almost every quantity has more than one possible representation. Consider exact value 123.456.  A decimal is the combination of a 96 bit integer, a 1 bit sign, and an eight-bit exponent that represents a number from -28 to 28.  That means that exact value 123.456 could be represented by decimals 123456 x 10<sup>-3</sup> or 1234560 x 10<sup>-4</sup> or 12345600 x 10<sup>-5</sup>. **Scale matters.**

**The C# specification also mandates how information about scale is computed.** The literal 123.456m would be encoded as 123456 x 10<sup>-3</sup>, and 123.4560m would be encoded as 1234560 x 10<sup>-4</sup>.

Observe the effects of this feature in action:

```
decimal d1 = 111.111000m;
decimal d2 = 111.111m;
decimal d3 = d1 + d1;
decimal d4 = d2 + d2;
decimal d5 = d1 + d2;
Console.WriteLine(d1);
Console.WriteLine(d2);
Console.WriteLine(d3);
Console.WriteLine(d4);
Console.WriteLine(d5);
Console.WriteLine(d3 == d4);
Console.WriteLine(d4 == d5);
Console.WriteLine(d5 == d3);
```

This produces

```
111.111000
111.111
222.222000
222.222
222.222000
True
True
True
```

Notice how information about significant zero figures is *preserved* across operations on decimals, and that decimal.ToString knows about that and displays the preserved zeroes if it can. Notice also how decimal equality knows to make comparisons based on exact values, even if those values have different binary and string representations.

The spec I think does not actually say that decimal.ToString() needs to correctly print out values with trailing zeroes based on their scales, but it would be foolish of an implementation to not do so; I would consider that a bug.

I also note that the internal memory format of a decimal in the CLR implementation is 128 bits, subdivided into: 16 unused bits, 8 scale bits, 7 more unused bits, 1 sign bit and 96 mantissa bits. The exact layout of those bits in memory is not defined by the specification, and if another implementation wants to stuff additional information into those 23 unused bits for its own purposes, it can do so.  In the CLR implementation the unused bits are supposed to always be zero.

Comment: @Eric: The Microsoft C# spec seems to lock `decimal` down a lot tighter than the ECMA spec (excerpts quoted in my answer). It would seem that the MS spec guarantees the *exact* behaviour of `decimal` whereas ECMA-334 allows some leeway. For example, one ECMA-conformant implementation might theoretically have a 12-bit exponent, a 112-bit mantissa and also allow signed zeros, infinities and NaNs -- according to my interpretation -- while another might follow the MS spec. If that were the case then computed values would not be guaranteed to be the same on every (ECMA-compliant) platform.

Comment: @Eric: And, out of interest... Did the MS spec ever have similar wording to the ECMA spec? I only have the MS v3 and v4 specs to hand and they're both pretty-much in agreement. If the wording of MS and ECMA was closer at some point then presumably you guys went on to make a fairly significant breaking change to your spec.

Comment: @LukeH: That's an excellent question; I did not even think to check the ECMA spec. I just assumed that the wording in the C# 4 spec was unchanged since The Before Time.  If I have some free time I'll look into it.

Comment: Is the difference in exponents stored for 0.0m vs. 0.00m? Is there any value in that?

Comment: @James: I would expect so, as the value in that is the same as the value in differentiating 0.1m from 0.10m: it communicates the amount of precision.

Comment: @James, @Timwi: Correct, we preserve the scale in 0.000.  That appears to contradict the spec statement that "a zero result always has a scale of zero". I am not sure why the spec says that; it is strange. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 5):

The `decimal` type is represented in what amounts to base-10 using a struct (containing integers, I believe), as opposed to `double` and other floating-point types, which represent non-integral values in base-2. Therefore, `decimal`s are **exact** representations of base-10 values, within a standardized precision, on any architecture. This is true for any architecture running a correct implementation of the .NET spec.

So to answer your question, since the behavior of `decimal` is standardized this way in the specification, `decimal` values should be the same on any architecture conforming to that spec. If they don't conform to that spec, then they're not really .NET.

["Decimal" .NET Type vs. "Float" and "Double" C/C++ Type](http://gregs-blog.com/2007/12/10/dot-net-decimal-type-vs-float-type/)

Comment: Thanks, but that leaves the question whether Mono uses a “correct implementation” under that criterion. I’ll accept an answer that addresses this.

Comment: @Timwi: You're asking if a specific implementation of the .NET framework is correct according to the specification. This is distinctly different from the question you originally asked. Knowing if an implementation is correct is a little more difficult though you should be able to confirm this yourself by looking at the specification and running some unit tests.

Comment: @Timwi: Any implementation of `decimal` will work this way; it's the point of the datatype. It's designed to be an exact representation of the number. When I said 'correct implementation' perhaps I was being overly cautious; really, *any* implementation of .NET must follow this standard, or it's not .NET at all. However, if you're curious and want to see for yourself, I believe this is the source for Mono's implementation: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System/System/Decimal.cs.htm

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic in your first sentence. The double type is also implemented using a struct containing integers, and in fact, they are the same integers as the decimal type. A double contains a one-bit integer which is the sign, an 11 bit integer which is the exponent, and a 52 bit integer which is the mantissa. A decimal contains a one-bit integer which is the sign, an 8 bit integer which is the exponent, and a 96 bit integer which is the mantissa. The only difference is that in a double, the exponent is a power of two and in decimal, the exponent is a power of ten.

Comment: I also am not following the logic of your second sentence. The decimal value 1.0m / 3.0m is not the exact value of one third; it is an approximation of one third accurate to about 28 decimal places or so. The double value 1.0 / 3.0 is not the exact value of one third either; it is an approximation accurate to about 15 decimal places. Doubles are exact representations of binary values and approximations of decimal values; decimals are exact representations of decimal values. But both are inexact representations of, say, numbers which could be represented exactly in base three.

Comment: My point is that doubles are exact representations of particular numbers every bit as much as decimals are exact representations of particular numbers. They're just exact representations of *different sets of numbers*. The set of numbers which can be represented exactly that was chosen for decimal is the set that is most useful for financial calculations.

Comment: @Eric: Yes, I found it a little difficult to express the difference succinctly while still addressing the question. I at first wrote it to say that `decimal` represents noninteger values in base-10 form vs. `float` and `double` using base-2, but that seemed misleading to me. I think your statement "Doubles are exact representations of binary values and approximations of decimal values; decimals are exact representations of decimal values" is the best way to describe the difference.

Comment: @Eric: Edited the wording to address your point a little better, while trying not to change the accepted answer too much. Does it seem correct to you?

Answer (score 5):

Even though the format of floating point types is clearly defined, floating point calculations can indeed have differing results depending on architecture, as stated in [section 4.1.6 of the C# specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e):

> Floating-point operations may be
>   performed with higher precision than
>   the result type of the operation. For
>   example, some hardware architectures
>   support an “extended” or “long double”
>   floating-point type with greater range
>   and precision than the double type,
>   and implicitly perform all
>   floating-point operations using this
>   higher precision type. Only at
>   excessive cost in performance can such
>   hardware architectures be made to
>   perform floating-point operations with
>   less precision, and rather than
>   require an implementation to forfeit
>   both performance and precision, C#
>   allows a higher precision type to be
>   used for all floating-point
>   operations.

While the `decimal` type is subject to approximation in order for a value to be represented within its finite range, the range is, by definition, defined to be suitable for financial and monetary calculations. Therefore, it has a higher precision (and smaller range) than `float` or `double`. It is also more clearly defined than the other floating point types such that it would appear to be platform-independent ([see section 4.1.7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e) - I suspect this platform independence is more because there isn't standard hardware support for types with the size and precision of `decimal` rather than because of the type itself, so this may change with future specifications and hardware architectures).

If you need to know if a specific implementation of the `decimal` type is correct, you should be able to craft some unit tests using the specification that will test the correctness.

Comment: Though the spec distinguishes between "decimal" and the two "floating point" types, this is a bit of a misnomer. The position of the decimal point can "float" in decimal too, so it could reasonably be classified as a "floating point" type. I don't think it is worth the hassle of changing the spec now though.

Comment: @Eric: Can't argue with you - I would lose. I have updated my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Note also that decimal, double and float *all* represent approximations; decimal is not arbitrary precision, so if you perform a multiplication or division that would produce more precision than decimal can handle, the result will be rounded and therefore will be an approximation. The difference between the binary and decimal types is not that one is exact and the other is an approximation; the difference is that the set of numbers which *are* represented exactly in the decimal type is the set of numbers most useful for financial calculations.

Comment: Re: arguing with me: you may have misinterpreted me; my first comment was not intending to point out a flaw in your answer, it was intended to point out a flaw in the specification. (My second comment was intended to point out a (minor) flaw in your answer.)

Comment: @Eric: Being schooled in public again - I can feel a letter to my parents coming on. Let's see if I can edit this in there.

Comment: @Eric: Updated to clear up the differences between the floating point types and why decimal is currently hardware independent. I might be learning too much today - I think I'm getting hives.

Answer (score 5):

A reading of the specification suggests that `decimal` -- like `float` and `double` -- *might* be allowed some leeway in its implementation so long as it meets certain minimum standards.

Here are some excerpts from the [ECMA C# spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) (section 11.1.7). All emphasis in bold is mine.

> The `decimal` type can represent values **including** those in
>   the range 1 x 10<sup>−28</sup> through 1 x 10<sup>28</sup> with
>   **at least** 28 significant digits.
>
> The finite set of values of type `decimal` are of the form
>   (-1)<sup>*s*</sup> x *c* x 10<sup>-*e*</sup>, where the sign *s*
>   is 0 or 1, the coefficient *c* is given by 0 <= *c* < *Cmax*,
>   and the scale *e* is such that *Emin* <= *e* <= *Emax*, where
>   *Cmax* is **at least** 1 x 10<sup>28</sup>, *Emin* **<=** 0, and
>   *Emax* **>=** 28. The `decimal` type **does not necessarily**
>   support signed zeros, infinities, or NaN's.
>
> For `decimal`s with an absolute value less than `1.0m`, the
>   value is exact to **at least** the 28<sup>th</sup> decimal
>   place. For `decimal`s with an absolute value greater than or
>   equal to `1.0m`, the value is exact to **at least** 28 digits.

*Note that the wording of the [Microsoft C# spec](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E) (section 4.1.7) is significantly different to that of the ECMA spec. It appears to lock down the behaviour of `decimal` a lot more strictly.*

Comment: I looked into it. At the time of the ECMA spec standardization there were members of the technical committee from other companies who had considerable interest and expertise in the IEEE standard for base-ten floating point. Apparently they argued that if an implementation could use hardware-based IEEE-compliant decimal arithmetic on hypothetical future chips that implemented it, then a conforming implementation ought to be allowed to do so provided that a minimum standard for precision and accuracy was met. The language you see in the spec was the resulting compromise.

Comment: @Eric - I'm sometimes amazed at the detail of the original C# design notes, assuming that's where you got this from. I'm also amazed by your ability to locate stuff like this.

Comment: @Justin: Indeed, however, in this case I just asked the guy who wrote that part of the spec what he was thinking that day. Since he has the office next to mine, it was not difficult to locate him.