# Decimal type in C# vs IEEE-754 standard

Tags: c#, double, decimal

Is Decimal type in C# follow the same rules (formula,normalized/denormalized,implied 1,Exponent bias) of classic double representation (IEEE-754 standard) except the use of base 10 instead of base 2.

What does implied the use of base 10 instead of base 2 ?

Is there, like "IEEE-754 double", the same behavior namely some gaps between adjacent values even for a finite precision (like 28/29 digits)?

Comment: Any representation of real numbers that uses finite memory has to contain gaps between adjacent values.

Comment: AFAIK decimal is not compatible with anything - it's a Microsoft only invention - so you can't think of it in the same terms as normal floating point stuff. And it doesn't have subnormal values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, C# `decimal` doesn't follow the same rules as IEEE 754 floating point numbers. The C# 4 specification is quite clear on how it should behave (§4.1.7):

> The `decimal` type is a 128-bit data type suitable for financial and monetary calculations. The decimal type can represent values ranging from 1.0 × 10<sup>−28</sup> to approximately 7.9 × 10<sup>28</sup> with 28-29 significant digits.
>
> The finite set of values of type `decimal` are of the form (–1)<sup>*s*</sup> × *c* × 10<sup>-*e*</sup>, where the sign *s* is 0 or 1, the coefficient *c* is given by 0 ≤ c < 296, and the scale *e* is such that 0 ≤ *e* ≤ 28. The `decimal` type does not support signed zeros, infinities, or NaN's. A `decimal` is represented as a 96-bit integer scaled by a power of ten. For `decimal`s with an absolute value less than `1.0m`, the value is exact to the 28th decimal place, but no further. For `decimal`s with an absolute value greater than or equal to `1.0m`, the value is exact to 28 or 29 digits. Contrary to the `float` and `double` data types, decimal fractional numbers such as 0.1 can be represented exactly in the `decimal` representation. In the `float` and `double` representations, such numbers are often infinite fractions, making those representations more prone to round-off errors.

Comment: There's a further discussion of the guarantee(s) given by the C# specification(s) in the answers and comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018187/is-net-decimal-arithmetic-independent-of-platform-architecture