# Why doesn't the decimal class use the remaining 26 bits?

Tags: c#, decimal

The decimal class uses 96 bits for the integral part, 1 bit for the sign, and 5 bits for the scaling factor. 26 bits are unused, and the max value is 7.9e28 because the maximum exponent is 28.

Using the other 26 bits, the precision would be higher. What's the reason for this implementation choice?

Comment: 23 bits, not 26. And see the final sentence of [this answer from Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5019178/3419534) to a previous question.

Comment: It existed long before .NET.  At least OLE Automation in VB4, might well go back further with nonzero odds for Excel or Lotus 123 being involved.  Still somewhat visible in the internal System.Currency type.  Fairly sure that 16 of the unused bits were used to store the kind of currency and the remaining 7 bits are alignment padding.  This is all lost in the fog of time, impossible to be accurate.

Comment: @HansPassant can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find this article useful:

http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/decimal.aspx

128 is 4 x 32. Most CPU's have 32 (or 64) bit registers and ALUs, so anything that is divisible by 32 will be much easier to manipulate and store etc.

Comment: That's true, but the type could have either used slightly fewer mantissa bits and been able to fit in three words, or used a few more and filled out the 128.  Actually, what I would have liked to have seen would have been a 128-bit fixed-point type which was stored as a 96-bit signed integer number of 256ths and a 32-bit unsigned number of trillionths (a value of 0.01 would be stored as 2/256 + 78,125,000/1,000,000,000).  Multiplication and division operations would require multiplying and dividing by 3,906,250,000 which is a 32-bit number (unlike 1,000,000,000,000).

Comment: Or use all the 128 bits to get a higher precision and range.

Comment: Using 128 bits would be slower, but there some 128 bit numeric types like Decimal in .NET